# how to write combined body onload function with json encode array

Tags: javascript, php

Hi all I am new on this forum.
I am trying to write a javascript function on body `onload` event and `json_encode`
for an array.But the function is not getting called.I was debugging in IE.

It is giving syntax error.Please tell me how I can write both on body `onload`.
Please see my code.

```
<body onLoad="<?php echo json_encode($EquipmentProblemArr); echo                                                                                                              json_encode($EquipmentAccessoryArr);?> displayHide1(<?php echo $EquipmentTypeRecID;?>);">

      function displayHide1(str)
      {
       document.getElementById("probNaccColmn").innerHTML="";

      if(str==4)
         {
    document .getElementById("R1").style.display="none"; //Make
    document.getElementById("R2").style.display="none"; //ModelNo
    document.getElementById("R3").style.display="none"; //Serial No.
    document.getElementById("R4").style.display="none"; //AED
    document.getElementById("R5").style.display="none"; //ServiceTag
    document.getElementById("R6").style.display="table-row";//EmployeeName
    document.getElementById("R7").style.display="table-row";//Problem
    document.getElementById("R8").style.display="none"; //Accessory
        }   
       else{
       document.getElementById("R1").style.display="table-row";
       document.getElementById("R2").style.display="table-row";
       document.getElementById("R3").style.display="table-row";
       document.getElementById("R4").style.display="table-row";
       document.getElementById("R5").style.display="table-row";
       document.getElementById("R6").style.display="table-row";
       document.getElementById("R7").style.display="table-row";
       document.getElementById("R8").style.display="table-row";
       }    
}
```

Comment: Put function in window.onload = ... and do the ajax from there. The php is on server side, js on client side. If you have the array populated allready, you don't need ajax

Answer (score 0):

Welcome.

The function is not called, because you are just declare it and do not run it. And I am not really sure what you are doing with your php code there...

First thing you should do is declare the function shomewhere in a script tag. Then call it in the onload-tag.

```
<script>
 function displayHide(str)
{
...
}
</script>

....

<body onload="displayHide(XXXX)">
```

The interesting stuff is now the XXXX, the parameter you want to give to your displayHide function. I guess it is somewhere hidden in your $EquipmentProblemArray. Maybe you could post here what is inside there. You access it via:

```
<script> var stuff=<?php echo json_encode($EquipmentProblemArr);?>;</script>
```

When it is an array, you maybe want to iterate over it and pass it to your displayHide-Function?